# WinForms C# xl.Visible and xl.UserControl commands not working properly

Tags: c#, excel, winforms

I am sorry if this is a very dumb question. I have a function that opens up an Excel (that I use as a template) adds text to a cell and then exports to PDF on a different path, but for some reason the `xlMedicoes.Visible = false` and `xlMedicoes.Visible = false` commands don't seem to be working, I still get a "Do you want to save the changes you made to this Document?" window pop up. I am a newbie so any help would be appreciated.

```
        xlMedicoes = new Excel.Application();
        xlWorkBook = xlMedicoes.Workbooks.Open("C:\\Verificacao de Quadros Eletricos\\EPLAF\\OF127_MEDICOES_EPLAF");
        xlWorkSheet = xlWorkBook.Worksheets["Folha1"]; 

        xlMedicoes.Visible = false;
        xlMedicoes.UserControl = false;

        xlWorkSheet.Cells[13, 9].Value += dateTimePicker1.Text; 

        string Directory = "C:\\Verificacao de Quadros Eletricos\\EPLAF\\" + textBox4.Text + "\\" + textBox3.Text + "\\OF127_MEDIÇÕES_" + dateTimePicker1.Text;
        xlWorkBook.ExportAsFixedFormat(Excel.XlFixedFormatType.xlTypePDF, Directory);
        xlWorkBook.Close();
        xlMedicoes.Quit();

        System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlMedicoes);
        System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlWorkBook);
        System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlWorkSheet);

    }
```

Comment: Have you tried to tell it to not to save the changes when you close the Workbook? - Reference [Workbook.Close method (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbook.close). The Visible properties only apply to what you can see, not underlying functionality

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
xlWorkBook.Close(false);
```

instead of `xlWorkBook.Close();`. That should discard any changes without asking.